# please help in configuring opencv 2.4.8 on qt(vs2012) on 64bit windows7

Tags: qt, opencv

I have 64bit intel machine.
I am running windows 7 (64 bit) on this machine.
I have installed Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 on my machine.
I have installed Qt Creator 3.0.1 based on Qt 5.2.1 (MSVC 2010, 32bit)
I am not able to configure opencv 2.4.8 on this Qt on my machine.
I have tried many things but I am not able to get opencv 2.4.8 work on qt.
Please tell me the necessary steps.
Please note, I guess there is some twist because of my software versions e.g. 64 bit machine, opencv 2.4.8 and qt based on MSVC2010, but I am not sure.
Please..please..please help me.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Qt for MSVC2010 won't ever work with MSVC2012. You need to download a version that matches your compiler, *or* recompile Qt using MSVC2012.

Answer (score 0):

Are you failing to compile OpenCV, link it with your application or running your executable from Qt? Are you linking statically? The problems can be quite different.

If you are linking statically everything needs to be compiled with the same Microsoft Visual C++ compiler AFAIK [VC11 (2012) in your case]. OpenCV is Ok because they provide binaries for vc10 (VS2010), vc11 (VS2012) and vc12 (VS2013). For Qt itself download the version compiled against VS2012 available [here](http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.2/5.2.1/qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2012-5.2.1.exe).

If you are required to use Qt libraries compiled against vc10, then make sure you install the redistributables for Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86) and link your application dynamically. And of course, use Dependency Walker if you have problems with wrong DLLs.